# Set operations in DBIx::Class

Tags: database, perl, dbix-class, set-operations

What is the best way to perform set operations using DBIx::Class?
I saw that one solution would be to create a Result Source based on my query, but my conditions will be defined by the user and I don know if the best answer is to create the result source on the fly.

Basically i need to translate this type of query to DBIC where `code`, `attr_name` and `value` is defined by the user:

```
SELECT pid FROM product WHERE code = 48
INTERSECT
(
  ( SELECT pid FROM attr WHERE attr_name = 'color' AND value = 'blue'
    INTERSECT
    SELECT pid FROM attr WHERE attr_name = 'size' AND value = 'big'
  )
  UNION
  ( SELECT pid FROM attr WHERE attr_name = 'color' AND value = 'green'
    INTERSECT
    SELECT pid FROM attr WHERE attr_name = 'size' AND value = 'small'
  )
)
```

Comment: When you say defined by the user do you mean there may be more or less than the 9 placeholders above?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The user can define many filters using pairs of (attr_name, value) and intersections and unions.

Answer (score 2):

Could [DBIx::Class::Helper::ResultSet::SetOperations](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx%3a%3aClass%3a%3aHelper%3a%3aResultSet%3a%3aSetOperations) be what you need?

Comment: Actually I cannot use this DBIC Helper because Im on a project with several groups and we all use the same database schema and the same DBIC layer. And to use this module I will have to change my Resultset Base Class and I need to keep compatibility with the other groups.